# What affects tax due for the Ohio vehicle tax penalty?

Tags: united-states, taxes, penalty, ohio

I bought a motorcycle for $3,000 and stupidly put $0 on title. I got a letter asking the sale price and paid $210 in taxes in response to the letter. Now I just got another letter that says I owe another $317.51 in taxes. I understand a penalty and interest, but why are they charging me an extra ~$275 for taxes I already paid?

Just the difference ($275)not including penalty and interest is more taxes than a person who bought a motorcycle in excellent condition from a dealer would pay. I'm super confused.

[image]

Comment: Did the rest of the letter specify the value of the vehicle they used in the calculation?

Comment: No, it does not. That's all it says other than a few pages of information they probably send with every notice.

Comment: I spent 45 minutes on the phone and got them to cancel the new amount owed. I think they made a mistake.